# How to see all the code from the Example on pub.dev/packages

Tags: firebase, flutter, authentication

When looking at the Examples in the pub.dev/packages, the code for some contained with one page, while the more advanced ones are not showing all the code. For example, in the firebase_auth package, the Example shows the main.dart file, while the most important code is probably at the other two imported files:

```
import './register_page.dart';
import './signin_page.dart';
```

My question - How do I see the two files?

Thanks, Gal.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this package by call some function and use IDE to jump to definition for example command + click in VS code.

Or you can open library file in directory `flutter_dir/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/name_of_lib/lib`

Comment: Thanks for the response, and indeed looking through the functions is sometimes helpful. I am trying to find the example code that the packages developers were kind enough to provide. That will provide additional help for me.